# IIS 8.5 / use two handlers

Tags: asp.net, iis, handler, httphandler

We have a ASP.NET application running in IIS 8.5 that we'd like to use two IIS handlers with. The handlers are:

1. OracleWebGateExtension: should process all requests to ensure that
   the user is authenticated
2. ChartImageHandler: should process requests for ChartImg.axd to generate reports

Our issue is that it seems the first handler processes all requests and the second handler never gets to process ChartImg.axd URLs.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to have two handlers process the same request? I think the answer is no, but I cannot find any documentation stating this.
2. (a) If the answer to #1 is no, then is there a good way to update the first handler to exclude URLs that the second handler needs to process? (b) If the answer to #1 is yes, then how do we need to change our web.config entries to make both handlers process the request for ChartImg.axd URLs?

Here's details on how the web.config files are structured (unnecessary details removed)

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <add name="OracleWebGateExtension" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_1\webgate\iis\lib\webgate.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\**app**\web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
        <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Forgive me I don't know everything about your codebase or requirements but why are you using a Handler to make sure users are authenticated? How are you handling authentication and authorization system wide? Because if you needed to perform an action on every request you should be using IHTTPMODULE anyway and only use handlers for specific request patterns (".[*]")

Comment: @DtechNet Good question. All of this is vendor code so I have no insight into things because configuration in the web.config.

Comment: Alright so you're dealing with a problem somewhat outside of your control - good question you have presented then. I don't think you can have two handlers be REGISTERED in the web.config to process the same request because the request would be ping ponging back and forth between each other or some kind of loop would occur. I could be wrong but I don't think the handlers will consume the same request as registered in the web.config in parallel. If you could edit the code then you could chain the responses between the two handlers and process the request down the line as you see fit. Good luck!